# Execute function identified by name

Tags: python

I'd like to run a function that is identified by a string.

```
toRun = 'testFunction'

def testFunction():
    log.info('In the function');

run(toRun)
```

Where `run` would be whatever command I need to use. I've tried with `exec`/`eval` without much luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

[`locals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) returns a dict containing references in the current scope

```
locals()[toRun]()
```

Answer (score 2):

Better use a dictionary that maps strings to functions.

```
def func1():
    print("in function 1")

def func2():
    print("in function 2")


functions = {
    "func1": func1,
    "func2": func2
}

# Get function by name.
the_func = functions["func1"]
# Execute it.
the_func()
```

Answer (score 2):

The build in function [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) can be used to return an named attribute of the object passed as argument.

**Example**

```
>>> import sys
>>> def function():
...     print 'hello'
... 
>>> fun_object = getattr( sys.modules[ __name__ ], 'function')
>>> fun_object()
hello
```

**What it does**

- `sys.modules[ __name__ ]` returns the current module object.
- `getattr( sys.modules[ __name__ ], 'function')` returns an attribute by the name `function` of the object, `sys.modules[ __name__ ]` which is the current object.

  - [Read more about sys.modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules)
- `fun_object()` calls the returned function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`

```
eval("testFunction()") # must have brackets in order to call the function
```

Or you could

```
toRun += "()"

eval("eval(toRun)")
```

Comment: You *can* use `eval`. But don't do it if it isn't absolutely necessary.